# ADB install the app but closes him self in Windows 7

Tags: titanium, adb, appcelerator

I try to run a simple default Alloy project with liveview mode ON and it gives that error:

```
[TRACE] :  Executing: C:\Users\pedro\Downloads\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 49OVGEZHUKVK8TH6 install -r -d C:\Users\pedro\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\deletar2\build\android\bin\deletar2.apk
[LiveView] version 1.0.9
[LiveView] File Server Started on Port 8324
[LiveView] Alloy project monitor started
[LiveView] Event Server Started on Port 8323
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
[ERROR] :  Failed to install apk on "49OVGEZHUKVK8TH6"
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

The liveview SEEMS works fine, SEEMS because before that error, if I change something and save, the liveview responds automatically. But after that error, whatever I do the liveview doesn't update, actually the app gives that error when I try to load it in the mobile.

[response in the mobile it self](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP8YL.jpg)

Yes, the mobile and the computer are on same network

Given that liveviews seems works, when I try to use the command below(which I take from the log) in the prompt directly, it gives error too.

> ```
> C:\Users\pedro\Downloads\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 49OVGEZHUKVK8TH6 install -r C:\Users\pedro\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\deletar2\build\android\bin\deletar2.apk
>
> [100%] /data/local/tmp/deletar2.apk
>         pkg: /data/local/tmp/deletar2.apk
> Success
> rm failed for -f, No such file or directory
> ```

As you can see, it says that it's a sucess but the ADB gives the 'Not responding alert' then it closes. 
[adb closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBuhk.png)

I tried the adb installed with the appcelerator and the latest in the android studio.
The firewall is deactivated.
I tried in two mobiles android of diferent versions.
The liveview and the command was used in others two windows(7 and 10) and Mac and worked just fine.

Can someone help me? I tackling this for over about two months(Yeah Crazy!)

Comment: Does it work without liveview?

Comment: That's another point, in appcelerator studio, it givest that error:
 [INFO] : Installing app on device: LG-E455 

 [TRACE] : Executing: C:\Users\pedro\Downloads\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows\android‌​-sdk-windows\platfor‌​m-tools\adb.exe -s 49OVGEZHUKVK8TH6 install -r -d C:\Users\pedro\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\delet‌​ar2\build\android\bi‌​n\deletar2.apk [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
 [ERROR] : Failed to install apk on "49OVGEZHUKVK8TH6"
 [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1